# What are the small plants growing in the soil with my palm tree?

Tags: identification, houseplants, palm

I have a [Chamaerops humilis](http://mobile.floridata.com/Plants/Arecacea/Chamaerops%20humilis/152) in my apartment, which has some small plants growing in the soil. I live in Denmark, Europe and my palm tree has only been inside my apartment since I got it.

What are the small plants?

*<sub>Click on photos for full size</sub>*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Sue. How did you change the pics so they fit together nicely? I see you added some new code to the back of the pictures but where did you get the new code which is this "oz9YDm.jpg", "GeEQCm.jpg", "Qhv09m.jpg"?

Comment: Extremely patient people here taught me what to do! The m on the end means I changed the picture to medium size, then linked it to the full size version. The instructions are [here](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/a/254/7305). If you want to play around with it, or anything else, go to the [Sandbox](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/261/). You'll see my many attempts at figuring it out! You can edit any of the answers, including mine, or add your own. You can save your work, and if you want it private, hit delete & only you'll see it. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: With the whorls possibly some galium or asperula - does it feel slightly "sticky" or "tacky"? Hairy?

Comment: @Stephie. Yes it feels sticky,  hairy:)

Comment: @Sue. I got it to work!! Check the post now: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9246/buddhist-shaolin-monks-and-their-practice.

Comment: Awesome! That post looks so great, and you figured it out much more quickly than I did!  Thanks for sharing that with me :)  I'm glad to see that you seem to be on your way to finding out what your little plant is!

Comment: @Sue. I would never have learned it without your help. Thank you for that. Yes i found out i got an answer on Biology SE. Someone correctly identified it. See here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35410/can-anyone-help-me-identify-this-plant

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted to [biology.se]: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35410/can-anyone-help-me-identify-this-plant